# Why does energy always wants to propagate?

Tags: energy

This might sound easy but its really a extremely fundamental question. The answer of this question has diverse implications. From thermodynamics to dark energy
The question is Why does energy always wants to propagate? In other words why does energy density always decrease per unit volume per unit time????

Answer (score 1):

It is called the *Second Law of Thermodynamics* : *The entropy of any isolated system always increases*.

To understand that fully, you need to understand the definition of *Entropy*, which is not trivial.

Simplified, *Entropy* is a measure of how unorganized / random a system is.
Ordered systems (like one place hot, another one cold) have a low Entropy ('unorganization'); left alone, the entropy will increase, resulting in higher 'unorganization' (all place about equally warm).

Comment: perhaps you should add that "laws" and "postulates" in physics are as necessary as mathematical axioms are for the mathematical model ( in this case thermodynamics). The answer to this "why" is because that is what we have observed.

Comment: Exactly this answer led me to this question...... I am trying to know why entropy of a system always increases.... And answer to this question is "Energy always wants to propagate"..... So logical flow of questions have led to this question....... Do you know the answer or any material (ie. Book, videos) that can help me ??

Answer (score 0):

First of all, energy does not always propagate. It depends upon what form of energy we are talking about. Energy rests (or is contained) in mass, and hence, the rest mass/energy. Gravitation causes the energy to collate, rather than spread.

Other forms of energy are waves and vibrations and I do not see any mystery in propagation of waves/vibrations.

Another form - kinetic energy, by definition is due to propagation.

Comment: Thanks but, I am not talking about energy stored in mass as E=mc^2 or gravitational confinement of energy black holes..... I am asking say "Why a photon energy particle of EM force always want to propagate?"

Comment: @AnomAhmed: It is not the photon energy that wants to propagate. It is photon energy because it is propagating. When the photon stops propagating, it is not energy anymore, it is not there anymore. It is a similar question as "why sound energy propagates" or "why the water wave energy propagate". The photon is also a wave which has to propagate in order to be a wave. There are standing waves, but they also propagate in a closed path.